# How to call a webmethod from jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am using visual studio 2015 and my project is ASP.NET Web Application. using Web Form template.

I can't call a webmethod from the jQuery ajax

Here is my webform aspx

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="EquipmentSubmitter.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowCurrentTime() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm2.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
                data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Your Name :
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time"
                onclick="ShowCurrentTime()" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my webform aspx.cs

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace EquipmentSubmitter
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
        {
            return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
                + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The breakpoint inside the webmethod is never reached.

Is there anything should be changed in the BundleConfig.cs or anywhere else?

Comment: Can you try 'url: "WebForm2/GetCurrentTime"'?  You shouldn't need the .aspx.

Comment: The definition of `data:` in your ajax call appears incorrect. `data: {name: $("#txtUserName").val()}`

Comment: Unfortunately, None of the suggestion worked

Answer (score 0):

Your web method is a `GET` and you're sending `data` - `data` is for POST methods. Change your URL to:

```
url: "WebForm2.aspx/GetCurrentTime?name=" + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question.

in the file **RouteConfig.cs** I changed this line

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permenant;
```

To this

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```